# Animateing stroke-width of a path in rapahel.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

Is there a way to animate the stroke-width property of a path in Raphael.js?
I want some arc paths to increase and decrease in their width by animation.

I wrote the following code but it didn't work.

```
var path = paper.path(...).attr({stroke: color, "stroke-width": 20, "stroke-opacity": 0.6})
path.animate({"stroke-width": 10});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate

You are supposed to specify some animation parameters such as timing and easing of the animation.

try

```
path.animate({"stroke-width": 10}, 5000);
```

for an animation lasting 5 seconds